# Allowing data to remain unclassified in Bayesian model selection

Tags: bayesian, model-selection

This is a follow up to a [previous question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/451801/what-to-do-if-the-rate-of-misclassification-in-bayesian-model-selection-depends). In my analysis, I am using a Bayesian model selection (using MCMC) to determine which model best fits several data sets. However, because I want to allow my model to also leave some datasets unclassified, I also included a complex model that is more general than either of the two models (see [here](https://link.springer.com/article/10.3758/s13428-014-0557-9) for more details on this approach).

Unfortunately, for some model parameters, the unclassified model seems to fit much better than both of the actual models. I can replicate this effect in a simulation:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(ggplot2)

N <- 10

reps <- 1000

P1 <- function(k1,k2,N) {
  beta(N-k2+k1+1,N-k1+k2+1)
}

P2 <- function(k1,k2,N) {
  beta(k2+k1+1,2*N-k1-k2+1)
}

P3 <- function(k1,k2,N) {
  beta(k1+1,N-k1+1)*beta(k2+1,N-k2+1)
}


v <- seq(0.01,0.99,by=0.01)

df <- expand.grid(v = v, i = seq_len(reps), mdl=c(1,2))

df$K1 <- map_dbl(df$v,function(v) rbinom(1,N,v))
df$K2 <- map2_dbl(df$v,df$mdl, function(v,mdl) ifelse(mdl == 1, rbinom(1,N,1-v), rbinom(1,N,v)) )


df$P1 <- P1(df$K1,df$K2,N)
df$P2 <- P2(df$K1,df$K2,N)
df$P3 <- P3(df$K1,df$K2,N)

# roulette wheel selection based on probabilities
select.rw <- function(p) {
  iv <- p/sum(p)
  pv <- runif(1,0, 1 )
  for(i in seq_along(iv)) {
    pv <- pv - iv[i]
    if(pv <= 0) {
      return( i )
    }
  }
}

# We do a roulette wheel selection to simulate model selection using MCMC
# Also randomly selecting removes artifacts that appear when P1==P2
df$ret <- df[,c("P1","P2","P3")] %>% array_branch(margin = 1) %>% map_dbl(select.rw)

df$ACC <- (df$mdl == df$ret) * 1
df %>% group_by(mdl,v) %>% summarize(M=mean(ACC)) %>% ungroup() %>% ggplot(aes(x=v,y=M,color=factor(mdl))) + geom_line()

df %>% group_by(mdl,v) %>% summarize(M1 = mean(ret==1),M2 = mean(ret==2),M3 = mean(ret==3)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=v,linetype=factor(mdl))) + 
  geom_line(aes(y=M1),color="green") + geom_line(aes(y=M2),color="blue") + geom_line(aes(y=M3),color="red")
```

If I look at the rate of misclassification in relation to the parameter $v$, then I find that models are more likely to become misclassified if $v$ is close to $0.5$:

[image]

In this simulation, this is no problem, because in the end I still get a $50/50$ classification rate for both actual models after classification, which fits the initial distribution.

Unfortunately, during analysis, I found that the parameters are not distributed equally for both classes. I can simulate this by choosing the parameter from a different distribution for the two models:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(ggplot2)

N <- 10

reps <- 1000

P1 <- function(k1,k2,N) {
  beta(N-k2+k1+1,N-k1+k2+1)
}

P2 <- function(k1,k2,N) {
  beta(k2+k1+1,2*N-k1-k2+1)
}

P3 <- function(k1,k2,N) {
  beta(k1+1,N-k1+1)*beta(k2+1,N-k2+1)
}


v <- seq(0.01,0.99,by=0.01)

df <- expand.grid(i = seq_len(reps*100), mdl=c(1,2))

# Unequal probabilities in either group
df$v <- ifelse(df$mdl == 1, rbeta(nrow(df),2,2), rbeta(nrow(df),0.5,0.5))

df$K1 <- map_dbl(df$v,function(v) rbinom(1,N,v))
df$K2 <- map2_dbl(df$v,df$mdl, function(v,mdl) ifelse(mdl == 1, rbinom(1,N,1-v), rbinom(1,N,v)) )


df$P1 <- P1(df$K1,df$K2,N)
df$P2 <- P2(df$K1,df$K2,N)
df$P3 <- P3(df$K1,df$K2,N)

# roulette wheel selection based on probabilities
select.rw <- function(p) {
  iv <- p/sum(p)
  pv <- runif(1,0, 1 )
  for(i in seq_along(iv)) {
    pv <- pv - iv[i]
    if(pv <= 0) {
      return( i )
    }
  }
}

# We do a roulette wheel selection to simulate model selection using MCMC
# Also randomly selecting removes artifacts that appear when P1==P2
df$ret <- df[,c("P1","P2","P3")] %>% array_branch(margin = 1) %>% map_dbl(select.rw)

(df$ret %>% factor() %>% summary())/nrow(df)
```

However, in this case I find that the final rate differs from the initial 50/50 rate for the two models because model 1 has a much higher chance of remaining unclassified:

```
> (df$ret %>% factor() %>% summary())/nrow(df)
      1       2       3 
0.29076 0.41503 0.29421
```

So my initial attempt of allowing the MCMC to keep some datasets as unclassified creates artifacts in the data.

Is there a way to either remove these artifacts ([see also my previous question on this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/451801/what-to-do-if-the-rate-of-misclassification-in-bayesian-model-selection-depends)) or to handle possible unclassified datasets differently that does not create these artifacts?